Googleカレンダーの勤務場所情報をGoogle Apps Scriptでスプレッドシートに抽出したいです。
Googleカレンダーの勤務場所情報をGoogle Apps Scriptでスプレッドシートに抽出したいのですが、イベント情報しか抽出されません。勤務場所の登録（カレンダー上部、日付の下に表示される機能）からGoogle Apps Scriptで情報を抽出することは可能でしょうか？
下記、現状使用しているコードです。「DBH」というオフィスへの社員の出社数をカウントしたく、作成しております。勤務場所登録機能で「自宅」or「DBH」を社員に登録させ、出社人数を把握するというものです。
function importDBHLocations() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var calendarIds = ['CALENDAR_ID_1', 'CALENDAR_ID_2']; // カレンダーIDをリストに追加する
  var startDate = getMonday(new Date()); // 今週の月曜日の日付を取得
  var endDate = new Date(startDate.getTime() + (4 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)); // 今週の金曜日の日付を取得

  var data = [['日付', 'DBHの数']]; // 列ヘッダー

  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) { // 月曜日から金曜日まで
    var date = new Date(startDate.getTime() + (i * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    var count = 0;
    
    for (var j = 0; j < calendarIds.length; j++) {
      var events = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarIds[j]).getEvents(date, endDate);
      
      for (var k = 0; k < events.length; k++) {
        var event = events[k];
        var location = event.getLocation();
        
        if (location === 'DBH') {
          count++;
          break; // 同じ日の重複イベントを避けるためにループを終了
        }
      }
    }

    data.push([Utilities.formatDate(date, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), 'yyyy/MM/dd'), count]);
  }

  // データをスプレッドシートに書き込む
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data);
}

// 指定した日付の月曜日を取得する関数
function getMonday(date) {
  var day = date.getDay();
  var diff = date.getDate() - day + (day == 0 ? -6 : 1); // 日曜日の場合は1日前に戻る
  return new Date(date.setDate(diff));
}


参考: 英語版での関連質問 - Google Apps Script: retrieving Working Location from calendar
